# scala in IntelliJ Idea: display differently immutable (val) vs mutable (var) variables?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to set syntax highlighting in IntelliJ Idea for scala code, so that **mutable** variables declared with `var` displays in different color (and/or style) than **immutable** variables (declared with `val` or function parameters)?

Eclipse has this by default, but I didn't find this is IntelliJ options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Scala

Looks like styles for vars can be separately configured for:

- Local Variable
- Template var

Comment: As of version 2021.2, the pathway has been changed to: File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Scala.

Comment: For "Local Variable" , I removed it from being inherited, changed it to Bold Foreground Black. And now, anytime I am reading through code, anything with `var` (i.e. local mutation) stands out like a sore thumb. I haven't played with "Template Var" as I haven't yet had to use `var` for a `class` or `trait`. If/when I do, I will be applying  a similar pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to set it for Kotlin in Android Studio, then by now (AS 4.0) it's under:
File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Kotlin > Keywords
You also have to uncheck the "Inherit values from" checkbox to be able to define different colors for `val` and `var`